# Build Failed while integrating Cruise Control with SVN

Tags: c#, .net, svn, cruisecontrol.net

I have setup Cruise Control on a Windows Server 2008 but I am receiving following error

> D:\repo\Net2Text\boloro\WebServices\trunk\msbuild.xml(58,3): error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.FileUpdate" task could not be loaded from the assembly \MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll)). Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll))' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, and that the assembly and all its dependencies are available.

I have tried installing "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.v1.4.0.88" but still unable to make it working.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Following is the information inside MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets

```
      <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath Condition="'$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>$([MSBUILD]::Unescape($(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll))</MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: _"Confirm that the declaration is correct, and that the assembly **and all its dependencies** are available"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have tried editing several file, one thing that is weird is that it point to D:\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll where as the location is in program file. I tried hardcoding this as well but it didn't work.

Comment: Seem like I am moving towards a solution. Initially the targeted installer was of 4.0 where I need 3.5